# Calculations with decimals with different LOCALE_ID not working, Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to do a mathematical calculations with decimals,

I have several inputs that make calculations among themselves, these entries are prices of items, to visualize them well, I changed the LOCALE_ID from angular to 'es'(spanish location), at the moment everything is fine, the numbers show them with the correct format applying the pipe | number.

The problem is ... when i make a calculation with a number that contain a decimal, the result is NaN, the reason is because it does not recognize the number for example 150,30€ (does not recognize the ",")

If I remove the LOCALE_ID, the format of the number becomes 150.30 € and the calculation does it perfectly ...

How can I fix it??

DEMO STACKBLITZ

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcmsga

Comment: Js always use '.' as decimal separator. Where this numbers come from? Show us some code.

Comment: here i made you a demo, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcmsga

Comment: @EliasSoares If you know how i could change the locale just for this component, i mean, i really dont care that this component has 'en-US' locale, but the rest of the app have to be with 'es' locale. i read something about change locale dynamically but i didn't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying differents ways and i couldn't solve it as i expected, JS cannot operate with decimal like this, "150,30" only like this "150.30"... so what i did is created a new pipe.

```
@Pipe({name: 'DecimalPipe'})

export class Decimals implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    var num1 = Math.floor(value * 100) / 100;
    return num1;
  }
}
```